# django - prefetch only the newest record?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to prefetch only the latest record against the parent record.

my models are as such

```
class LinkTargets(models.Model):
    device_circuit_subnet = models.ForeignKey(DeviceCircuitSubnets, verbose_name="Device", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    interface_index = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Interface index (SNMP)', blank=True, null=True)
    get_bgp = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="get BGP Data?")
    dashboard = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Display on monitoring dashboard?")


class LinkData(models.Model):
    link_target = models.ForeignKey(LinkTargets, verbose_name="Link Target", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    interface_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Interface Description', blank=True, null=True)
...
```

The below query fails with the error

```
AttributeError: 'LinkData' object has no attribute '_iterable_class'
```

Query:

```
link_data = LinkTargets.objects.filter(dashboard=True) \
                            .prefetch_related(
                                Prefetch(
                                    'linkdata_set',
                                    queryset=LinkData.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0]
                                    )
                                )
```

I thought about getting LinkData instead and doing a select related but ive no idea how to get only 1 record for each link_target_id

```
link_data = LinkData.objects.filter(link_target__dashboard=True) \
                            .select_related('link_target')..?
```

EDIT:

using rtindru's solution, the pre fetched seems to be empty. there is 6 records in there currently, atest 1 record for each of the 3 LinkTargets

```
>>> link_data[0]
<LinkTargets: LinkTargets object>
>>> link_data[0].linkdata_set.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>>
```

Comment: did u try use `.distinct('link_target_id`)`?

Comment: NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend. my dev env is using sqlite, my live site is using mysql

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is that `Prefetch` expects a Django `Queryset` as the `queryset` parameter and you are giving an instance of an object.

Change your query as follows:

```
link_data = LinkTargets.objects.filter(dashboard=True) \
                            .prefetch_related(
                                Prefetch(
                                    'linkdata_set',
                                    queryset=LinkData.objects.filter(pk=LinkData.objects.latest('id').pk)
                                    )
                                )
```

This does have the unfortunate effect of undoing the purpose of `Prefetch` to a large degree.

***Update***
This prefetches exactly one record globally; not the latest `LinkData` record per `LinkTarget`.

To prefetch the max LinkData for each LinkTarget you should start at LinkData: you can achieve this as follows:

`LinkData.objects.filter(link_target__dashboard=True).values('link_target').annotate(max_id=Max('id'))`

This will return a dictionary of {`link_target`: 12, `max_id`: 3223}

You can then use this to return the right set of objects; perhaps filter LinkData based on the values of `max_id`.

That will look something like this:

```
latest_link_data_pks = LinkData.objects.filter(link_target__dashboard=True).values('link_target').annotate(max_id=Max('id')).values_list('max_id', flat=True)
link_data = LinkTargets.objects.filter(dashboard=True) \
                            .prefetch_related(
                                Prefetch(
                                    'linkdata_set',
                                    queryset=LinkData.objects.filter(pk__in=latest_link_data_pks)
                                    )
                                )
```

Comment: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'LinkData' do I need to use values?

Comment: Updated - needed to do a `.pk` on the `get`

Comment: the prefetch is empty

Comment: ive added some more output to the question, it seems prefetches are empty

Comment: Sure, that's because your filter query does not filter by the `LinkTarget` -> it prefetches one `LinkData` record globally; not the record corresponding to each `LinkTarget` -> Look at my update

Answer (score 2):

The following works on PostgreSQL. I understand it won't help OP, but it might be useful to somebody else.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Prefetch
from .models import LinkTargets, LinkData

link_data_qs = LinkData.objects.order_by(
    'link_target__id',
    '-id',
).distinct(
    'link_target__id',
)

qs = LinkTargets.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'linkdata_set',
        queryset=link_data_qs,
    )
).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

`LinkData.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0]` is not a queryset, it is an model object, hence your error.

You could try `LinkData.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0:1]` which is indeed a QuerySet, but it's not going to work. Given how `prefetch_related` works, the queryset argument must return a queryset that contains all the `LinkData` records you need (this is then further filtered, and the items in it joined up with the LinkTarget objects). This queryset only contains one item, so that's no good. (And Django will complain "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken" and raise an exception, as it should).

Let's back up. Essentially you are asking an aggregation/annotation question - for each LinkTarget, you want to know the most recent LinkData object, or the 'max' of an 'id' column. The easiest way is to just annotate with the id, and then do a separate query to get all the objects.

So, it would look like this (I've checked with a similar model in my project, so it should work, but the code below may have some typos):

```
linktargets = (LinkTargets.objects
               .filter(dashboard=True)
               .annotate(most_recent_linkdata_id=Max('linkdata_set__id'))

# Now, if we need them, lets collect and get the actual objects
linkdata_ids = [t.most_recent_linkdata_id for t in linktargets]
linkdata_objects = LinkData.objects.filter(id__in=linkdata_ids)

# And we can decorate the LinkTarget objects as well if we want:

linkdata_d = {l.id: l for l in linkdata_objects}
for t in linktargets:
    if t.most_recent_linkdata_id is not None:
        t.most_recent_linkdata = linkdata_d[t.most_recent_linkdata_id]
```

I have deliberately **not** made this into a prefetch that masks `linkdata_set`, because the result is that you have objects that lie to you - the `linkdata_set` attribute is now missing results. Do you really want to be bitten by that somewhere down the line? Best to make a new attribute that has just the thing you want.

Comment: On this last point of not wanting to mask `linkdata_set`, I think you could have used `Prefetch(..., to_attr="most_recent_linkdata_set_of_one")` to achieve a similar result but with a `Prefetch`, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, but it seems to work:

```
class ForeignKeyAsOneToOneField(models.OneToOneField):
    def __init__(self, to, on_delete, to_field=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(to, on_delete, to_field=to_field, **kwargs)
        self._unique = False

class LinkData(models.Model):
    # link_target = models.ForeignKey(LinkTargets, verbose_name="Link Target", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    link_target = ForeignKeyAsOneToOneField(LinkTargets, verbose_name="Link Target", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='linkdata_helper')
    interface_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Interface Description', blank=True, null=True)


link_data = LinkTargets.objects.filter(dashboard=True) \
                               .prefetch_related(
                                    Prefetch(
                                        'linkdata_helper',
                                        queryset=LinkData.objects.all().order_by('-id'),
                                        'linkdata'
                                    )
                                )

# Now you can access linkdata:
link_data[0].linkdata
```

Ofcourse with this approach you can't use linkdata_helper to get related objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to you question, but solves the same problem. It is possible annotate newest object with a subquery, which I think is more clear. You also don't have to do stuff like `Max("id")` to limit the prefetch query.

It makes use of `django.db.models.functions.JSONObject` (added in Django 3.2) to combine multiple fields:

```
MainModel.objects.annotate(
    last_object=RelatedModel.objects.filter(mainmodel=OuterRef("pk"))
    .order_by("-date_created")
    .values(
        data=JSONObject(
            id="id", body="body", date_created="date_created"
        )
    )[:1]
)
```