# Django prefetch related with filter to keep only specific row

Tags: python, django, database, django-queryset, database-performance

Let's suppose that I have these simple models:

```
from django.db import models


class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to execute a queryset that fetch all authors, and annotate each author with its latest book name and date. This queryset should be the most efficient possible to avoid multiple subqueries for each needed column : this problem is a simplification of a real world application with many more fields.

Answering the case of a generic filtering would be great, I would however gladly settle for the specific case of filtering against latest date.

### What have been tried

#### Subquery

I could use [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), however, a subquery only returns one column, I would need to create one Subquery per columns (here it's just name and date but my real application case has many more fields).

```
books = Book.objects.filter(author=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')
qs = Author.objects.all().annotate(
    latest_book_name=Subquery(books.values('name')[:1]),
    latest_book_date=Subquery(books.values('date')[:1]),
)
```

This works, at least, but it feels really inefficient.

### Prefetch

I could use prefetch_related to retrieve all books associated with an author. I could then use Max to retrieve the max date but it does not contains the latest book name.

```
qs = Author.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch("books"))
qs = qs.annotate(latest_book_date=Max("books__date"))
```

as far as I know, there is no Argmax operator

### first, latest

Using first, or latest are not options since they do not provide queryset but single objects. I would not be able to use these values as annotations.

### matching id with max id

[Other users have solved similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220075/5118420) by annotating with Max("id") and then matching books id with max ids to only filter latest books, however books haven't been added in chronological order (my real world application does not even use incremental id but instead uuid).

Answer (score 0):

To debug query you should use this. Hope this will help you to make a choice.

```py
from django.db import connection

def display_sql():
    for sql in connection.queries:
        print(sql.get('sql'))
        print("\n")
```